# Use jQuery to recursively get the first parent of an element matched by a class filter

Tags: jquery, css, dom, jquery-selectors, traversal

I have a situation in which i need a reference to the very next DIV that is the parent of my current DIV, but matches a specific class name.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="something">test</div>
    <div class="something">test</div>
    <div class="something" onclick="$(use jquery to find parent with class container)">test</div>
</div>
```

This would be pretty easy, but it can also look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="someotherthing">
        <div class="something">test</div>
        <div class="something">test</div>
        <div class="something" onclick="$(use jquery to find parent with class container)">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which means that i am looking for a solution that recursively walks UP the dom until it finds a parent of a given element that matches a certain CSS class.

And i was wondering whether jQuery can do this in a one-shot call.

Comment: What you're asking for is better described as an ancestor rather than parent.  Parent usually means immediate ancestor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `.closest()` method should handle this:

```
 $(this).closest(".someclass")
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at jQuery [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method which get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Closest will return the first parent, whereas parents() will return all matching parents.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.something').parents('.container');
```

This will do what you want.

You should check out the documentation on [traversing the DOM](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.parents([selector])` to select the desired parent of any element:

```
$('.something').on('click', function () {
    var $parent = $(this).parents('.container:first');
});
```

This will select the first parent element that has the `container` class when any element with the `something` class is clicked.

Note that `.on()` is the preferred jQuery 1.7's version of the `.bind()` function.

Docs for `.parents()`: http://api.jquery.com/parents

Comment: `.bind()` is not depreciated.

Comment: For reference to the above comment, https://forum.jquery.com/topic/delegate-vs-on#14737000002878044 and the docs.

Comment: @KevinB I used the wrong wording, it's the "preferred" method: `...we recommend that you use .on() for any new jQuery project where you know version 1.7 or higher is in use`. Answer updated, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.something').parents('.container');
```